# Does ruptures index from 0 or 1?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I use the ruptures module to search for changes in trends, etc.  It returns an index value 1 greater than the date length, and it looks like it is indexing from 1 instead of 0. Or it is adding 1 to the last value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # for display purposes
import ruptures as rpt  # our package

n_samples, n_dims, sigma = 1000, 3, 2
n_bkps = 4  # number of breakpoints
signal, bkps = rpt.pw_constant(n_samples, n_dims, n_bkps, noise_std=sigma)

print(len(singal))

bkps = [217, 424, 629, 810, 1000]
```

I don't understand, do I just need to delete the last value, or do I need to make -1 for all values here?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? `rpt.pw_constant` only creates a demo signal with the true changepoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, `bkps` represent the index of the point that is just after the breakpoint. If you have a range index this means that the breakpoint is in between this point and the previous one.

Indeed, if we manually plot the breakpoint we need to subtract 0.5 to the x-value to align it to the graph:

```
n_samples, n_dims, sigma = 100, 2, 2
n_bkps = 4  # number of breakpoints
signal, bkps = rpt.pw_constant(n_samples, n_dims, n_bkps, noise_std=sigma, seed=0)

(f, axes) = rpt.display(signal, bkps)

for x in bkps:
    for ax in axes:
        ax.axvline(x-0.5, ls=':', c='k')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's just that this module always returns a value 1 more than the last index, and if you pass it as an index for drawing a line, it appears in the blank, which made me think that maybe it counts indices from 1 and not from 0, but I didn't really understand why the gap is -0.5, is it described somewhere? or how did you come to this?

Comment: @Roman try to change my code to plot `x-1` or `x` in place of `x-0.5`. You'll see the the line is either on the left or the right of the rupture. In addition, if you plot the markers you can observe that this boundary is in between two points. Thus we can conclude that the reported index is the point immediately after the rupture.